# Configuring OTB for Processing on Linux Mint

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing, orfeo-toolbox, linux-mint

I'm using QGIS 2.18.3 in Linux Mint 18. I have downloaded Orfeo Toolbox and want to add it to the processing toolbox in QGIS. I have done it under Windows indicating the bin and lib path, but on Mint doesn't work. I read https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/QGIS_access_to_OTB_applications but it doesn't seem logic that I have to build it from source just to do that. Anyone knows a easy/better way to do it?

Comment: I installed OTB from the regular ubuntugis-unstable repos and the tools appear in the QGIS processing toolbox. Nothing more to do...(I assume you have the qgis-providers package installed?).

Comment: No luck, I checked for qgis-providers package and ubuntugis-unstable, reinstall them, but nothing. Do you have to specify the paths in the Providers? I did that on Windows and worked fine.

Comment: I managed to install otb through the Package Manager of Mint, I an now able to use it from terminal. Now the path (checked) are /usr/bin and /usr/lib/otb/applications, I indicated the path in the processing toolbox settings, but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I am responding my own question because I have solved it for my own purpose. It doesn't mean that there could not be a better answer.

It seems to be due to the version. I downgrade to the LTR version of QGIS, and the Orfeo Toolbox appear in the processing toolbox!!

### My steps where:

Remove packages

```
sudo apt-get remove qgis python-qgis 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Add PPA (add lines in *etc/apt/sources.list*)

```
# QGIS LTR
deb     http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr xenial main
deb-src http://qgis.org/ubuntugis-ltr xenial main
deb     http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu xenial main
```

Update repository

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install QGIS

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```

Before you run QGIS for the first time, delete (or rename) the folder *home/user/.qgis2* where user is your linux user

That is it!